# How do I gain access to an existing application

Tags: facebook, web, administration

I have inherited an application that currently has an appId, but I need to change some of the other information.  I don't know what user controls the application.  How can I gain access to  an existing application?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track down who is currently the admin of the app, there's no other way.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you can clone git repository to your local machine -you can find address in app details. You should of course remove old ssh key and upload your public key instead - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: The OP wants to know how to get access to the app settings.